# Apache executes code in files that have .php prepended before extension ex: .php.txt , php.pdf

Tags: php, apache, execution

What can i do to stop Apache execute code in files that have .php prepended before extension ex: .php.txt , php.pdf , i do not know if this is related to webuzo admin panel n/or apache in general ?

Apache version 2.2.34

Opened thread on webuzo forum ,if anyone else has this issue , it might be related :
https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=17642

Comment: Shouldn't be related to apache, unless you modified handler(s).

Comment: i didn't modified anything related to handler/s ... i even uninstalled & reinstall apache .

Answer (score 2):

This is reasonably standard behaviour - [files can have multiple extensions on Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext). (As they can on [other OS / filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension).)

However, this behaviour can be avoided.

Whether files that end in `.php.txt` or `.php.pdf` are processed for PHP is dependent on how PHP is enabled on the server.

For example, if you simply use `AddHandler` then any file that *contains* a `.php` extension (like `.php.txt`) will be processed by the PHP handler:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

However, if you only call `SetHandler` on the specific file pattern, ie. when `.php` occurs at the end of the filename, then this behaviour can be avoided.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

NB: This is not a copy/pastable solution - it really depends on how PHP is implemented on your Apache web server.

Depending on your requirements you could potentially block requests to files that contain a `.php` extension, but not at the end of the URL-path. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php\.">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

NB: This is Apache 2.2 syntax (as stated in the question). If you are on Apache 2.4 then you'd use `Require all denied` instead of the `Order` and `Deny` directives in the last block.